# Using Behave to test asyncio application

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-behave

Is it possible to test an application based on `asyncio` events?  If not, what's a testing strategy for intra-process event bus testing in python?

My application is based on [pyee](https://pyee.readthedocs.io) using an event-bus to communicate between systems and [sismic](https://sismic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as the state machine.

In my application, I start it using `aiorun` as follows:

```py
from aiorun import run
async def main():
    app = TestApplication()
    await shutdown_waits_for(app.cleanup())

run(main())
```

In this case, `TestApplication` is a testing stub that is doing the event routing between the state machine and various sub-systems listening to the event bus.

What I'm trying to do is test the communication between systems.  To run, the `GuiApplication` has to be running in the event loop, so a give step definition (that isn't working) would be something like this:

```py
@when('I wait for message {message} to be fired containing {key}="{value}"')
@then('message {message} is fired containing {key}="{value}"')
@async_run_until_complete(timeout=1.2)
async def step_impl5(context, message, key=None, value=None):
    dict = {}
    if key:
        dict[key] = value
    ta = TestApplication()
    await ta.wait_for_message(message, dict)
```

However, the above terminates with `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

I've has a bit of success using [nest_asyncio](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio):

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

but this doesn't seem right either.

In short, how can I utilize the existing event loop for testing, or can I?

Answer (score 0):

You have two step decorators, `@when` and `@then`, for the same step implementation. There should only be one per step.

```
@when('I wait for message {message} to be fired containing {key}="{value}"')
def step_impl4(context, message, key=None, value=None):
    # set up context
    pass

@then('message {message} is fired containing {key}="{value}"')
@async_run_until_complete(timeout=1.2)
async def step_impl5(context, message, key=None, value=None):
    dict = {}
    if context.key:
        dict[key] = context.value
    ta = TestApplication()
    await ta.wait_for_message(message, dict)
```